# Become root on ssh client

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sudo, root

I'm trying install an agent named cloudamize with a bash script to our linux machines. There is two commands for this process:

```
export CLOUDAMIZE_CUSTOMER_KEY=<my_customer_key>
bash < <(curl -s https://agentmanager1.cloudamize.com/cxf/downloadFile/installCloudamizeAgentV2.sh)
```

But these commands need to be worked by root. Sudo command does not work. So I should connect to client via ssh and become root and then I should run these commands after that. So, below command does not work also:

```
for host in $(cat hostlist)
do
    ssh my_user@$host "\
    export CLOUDAMIZE_CUSTOMER_KEY=<my_customer_key>;\
    bash < <(curl -s https://agentmanager1.cloudamize.com/cxf/downloadFile/installCloudamizeAgentV2.sh)"
done
```

How can I be root before run these 2 commands in bash script? Or is there another way to do this? Because sudo -i or su does not work in bash script.

Comment: Does using `su` to switch to the root account work?  If not, wouldn't the best option be to add the SSH user to a sudo group in `/etc/sudoers`, or if you don't want the SSH user to have full `sudo` privileges, simply configure the user to only be able to access the specific binaries required for the install via `sudo`?

Comment: su works but i'm trying this in a bash script. the problem is this.

Comment: I configured a remote PC to run a bash script that required a `sudo` command within the script by adding the SSH user to `/etc/sudoers`... does this not work? _(I may not have edited my previous comment fast enough for you to see that)_

Comment: user can be root already. the problem is sudo/su command does not work in bash script. I added a line to question. thanks.

Comment: I'll have to dig up the script I wrote to see what I did to make this possible. It'll take me a day or two to figure out where I backed it up to, but someone should [hopefully] respond with an answer well before then.  _(When you have time, would you please place the commands you added, `sudo -i` and `su`,inside of two single backticks so they appear as inline monospaced text? Thanks =] )_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this

```
ssh -t my_user@$host 'sudo command'
```

or this?

```
ssh my_user@$host su -c "command"
```

Comment: thanks. i find another way: ssh user@host "sudo su -  -c 'commands'"